# MacBook with notch - hide menu bar in select apps

Tags: macos, menu-bar

I have a MacBook Pro M1 Pro with notch. The menu bar setting is set to never automatically hide in full screen or on desktop. This works great for 90% of the time, I like to have the menu bar always there, along with a notch, taking advantage of the extra screen real estate (safari, premiere, etc).

But in rare cases, such as IINA (media player), I want to have the menu bar hidden during full screen. Is there a way to change the menu bar hide behaviour for select apps?

Answer (score 1):

Visibility of the menu bar in full screen is controlled with the AppleMenuBarVisibleInFullscreen preference. This is set globally in System Preferences but can be set on specific apps too using `defaults`.

- Set the global setting:
  `defaults write -g AppleMenuBarVisibleInFullscreen -bool true`
- Override the global for one app:
  `defaults write bundle.identifier AppleMenuBarVisibleInFullscreen -bool true`
- Remove the override, falling back to the global:
  `defaults delete bundle.identifier AppleMenuBarVisibleInFullscreen`

where

- `bundle.identifier` is the Bundle Identifier of a specific app, e.g. the IINA video player is `com.colliderli.iina`,
- `true` is true or false for the menu bar to be visible in full screen.

Comment: Thank you so much!