# How can I hide the App Menus on menu bar?

Tags: macos, applications, menu-bar, third-party

[image]

No, not the menu bar. I want to hide application menus like `File Edit View` on the menu bar. I have searched for several hours and could not find a single solution to do it.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/0). What problem are trying to address by getting rid of the interface of the user and the app?  Does "full screen" not solve this for you?

Comment: @Allan This is not an XY problem. I don't want to hide the Application Menu as a second solution. I want to get rid of it as my primary goal: I want such an implementation where the Application Menu is hidden by default and only appears to the right when the Apple logo is clicked.

Comment: It still doesn't tell us why you are trying to circumvent the dev's intention or that decades of UI standardization are in issue now.

Comment: @Allan The Applications menu has too many buttons that hide necessary icons that the user has to pay for an external application to see. The notch on newer MacBooks exacerbates the problem, but too many application buttons is the problem here.

Comment: Does this work for you: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/462055/119271

Comment: @Allan I'm afraid that the thread you provided is unrelated to this thread.